# Move Item From One List to Another List that Has a Workflow Already (SP 2010 Designer)

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am attempting to move a document from a document library from its source list (that has a workflow assigned to it), to another list that has its own workflow assigned to it using SharePoint Designer 2010.  The problem is the item is never copied over.  When I test copying the list item to another list that does not have a workflow assigned to it, the item is ALWAYS copied over.

The workflow is as simply as this:
Copy item in Current Item to Destination List
then Delete item in Current Item

NOTE: the workflow initiates whenever the document is modified.

Is the workflow assigned to the destination list causing the problem?  If so, does anyone know how to remedy this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error while copying file to destination list? is there any event receiver attached to the list?

Comment: No errors.  No event receivers.  Interesting though, I have 3 lists that all begin with the same 4 letters (AAAB).  When the workflow runs, it doesn't copy the item to the list I specified, but goes to the next list with the same 4 letters (AAAB).  This third list will act as an archive of all completed documents, and this is the list that does not have a workflow assigned for it.